New Card visual in Power BI to display multiple different values from same column as separate cards
I am trying to find a way to show multiple cards within the new card visual for Power BI from one column. I have data that has 'date', 'kpi type' and 'kpi value' columns.
Using these I can create three separate old card visuals that are filtered to show only specific 'kpi type' as shown in the picture in the middle. I would like to replace these old card visuals with one new card visual, but I cannot figure out how to create multiple cards from the same column's values.
I could just create 3 measures that count 3 different type of kpis but I would like a more scalable solution that would automatically create new cards to visual as new 'kpi types' emerge. Is there a way to create measure that would split the 'kpi values' by 'kpi types' for the new card visual?
I tried to add the 'kpi value' to new card visual and it will just sum up all the 3 values and create 1 card (on the right of the picture). I cannot find a way to separate these 3 type of values from each other in new card visual with just one measure.
Problem example
